# How do i freeze a gui app written in python(pygame) using cxFreeze?

Tags: python, macos, cx-freeze

I am building a GUI python application on OSX. When I launch the application a console window pops up which I would like to hide.

I have set the executable type in cx_freeze to be `Win32Gui`. However, the application still creates a console window. How do I hide the console window on a mac?

Comment: Re-worded the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file extension of .py on .pyw. And change the settings so that .pyw files associated with a python. Look here https://superuser.com/questions/486816/how-do-i-associate-pyw-files-with-python-in-osx